# Missing EXIT_CODE in environment passed to an ExecStopPost process

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to restart a program after a SSL certificate renewal.

My plan was to check the exit code of the `acme-tiny` script. That script is the main part of a systemd service started daily using a systemd timer.

After reading some man pages I created`/etc/systemd/system/acme-tiny.service.d/cert_reload.conf` containing just:

```
[Service]
ExecStopPost=/usr/local/libexec/cert_reload
```

This part seems to work.

However I have expected that there will be certain environment variables present, namely `$SERVICE_RESULT`, `$EXIT_CODE`, and `$EXIT_STATUS` - see `man systemd.exec`.

But all the script is getting is this:

```
SHELL=/sbin/nologin
USER=acme
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/var/lib/acme
LOGNAME=acme
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Without any information about the acme script result I cannot know if a restart is needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version systemd do you have, as this feature is from 232 onwards.

Comment: @meuh Only 219 (latest CentOS). I guess that explains everything....thank you for solving my problem!